# How can I troubleshoot SSL timeouts via curl?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, curl, ubuntu-14.04, ups

I'm getting a timeout trying to consume UPS's online tools API through PHP + Curl. This issue started happening this morning. I can reproduce the issue using Curl directly on Ubuntu 14.04 from bash. However, on Ubuntu 16.04, I can connect without any issues.

UPS support wasn't particularly helpful:

> Which of these servers that have been completed to the TLS 1.2 migration is not known. It is suggested to make sure that your security protocol is enabled for TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 for the time being. Though having the full stack, should minimized problems, as negotiation will utilizes highest agreed upon supported protocol by both parties.

Here's the verbose output on 14.04:

```
root@ubuntu14-nyc2-01:/etc/ssl/certs# curl https://onlinetools.ups.com -v
* Rebuilt URL to: https://onlinetools.ups.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 153.2.228.76...
* connect to 153.2.228.76 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
*   Trying 153.2.224.76...
* After 86387ms connect time, move on!
* connect to 153.2.224.76 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to onlinetools.ups.com port 443: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to onlinetools.ups.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

If I simply try to connect via OpenSSL, it also times out:

```
root@ubuntu14-nyc2-01:/etc/ssl/certs# openssl s_client -connect onlinetools.ups.com:443
```

Any ideas what the problem is? Pointers on troubleshooting? Are you also having issue with this UPS API from Ubuntu 14.04?

Here are the versions of relevant libraries:

1. Curl: tried both 7.50, with OpenSSL/1.0.2h; 7.35, withOpenSSL/1.0.1f
2. OpenSSL: tried 1.0.2h and 1.0.1f

I tried pulling the cacerts from haxx.se and pointed Curl to it using the `--cacerts` arg, no luck.

I'm pretty much at a loss here ... what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connection time out is a TCP level problem and not a SSL/TLS problem. It is simply that it cannot connect to the host. You would not even manage to get a telnet or netcat to the peer in this case. Depending on how much targets are affected by the problem it might be a firewall or router problem on the targets end (i.e. only this target affected) or some general network issue on your end (i.e. most hosts do not work).

Comment: Thanks ... that was my hunch. The set of APIs I'm calling on my end is rather limited; the main other is PayPal and it is working fine. Your response was helpful material to share with UPS support - they are escalating to the next tier of support.

Comment: And ... heard back from the UPS folks. They changed something on their end and we're back in business. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: same issue I think:CURL ERR: => Err number: 35 Err message: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to onlinetools.ups.com:3128...

What was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question, but may be of interest to some people searching on ups + SSL/TLS issues... Buried deep in UPS website:

> **Important: 2017 Implementation Update**
>
> UPS will be making changes beginning **September 1, 2017 through
>   December 31, 2017** to support enhancing our security. During this time,
>   you may see intermittent failures for transactions using TLS1.0 or
>   earlier.
>
> Effective 12/31/2017, **UPS will only accept TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2
>   security protocols.** It is highly recommended that the most current
>   version, TLS 1.2, be implemented. After that date, any communication
>   requests submitted to UPS using older protocols (TLS 1.0 or earlier)
>   will fail.

https://www.ups.com/us/en/help-center/technology-support/data-security.page